# Issues creating multiple objects of same class

Tags: java, eclipse, class, object

I am trying to create multiple objects of the same class but I want the object names (the variable names) to be taken from a certain file. How can I do this?

For example:

```
Example one = new Example();
```

I want to do the same for multiple objects but i need them named `one`, `two`, `three`, `four`, ... (without knowing the exact number of objects and I can't simply just copy paste it and change `one` to `two` as I am reading them from a file). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you please tag the relevant language?

Comment: @Marty just tagged it now

Comment: Maybe OT: If you're reading the names from a file and using that to create objects, how do you reference the object from throughout the file (e.g. elsewhere in the file)?

Comment: You cannot make the name of a reference in Java a dynamic thing. It must be explicitly given in the code itself. The closest you can do to what I think you want to do is make a map of your `Example` objects with a `String` key pointing to each element where the value of the `String` is read from some file.

Comment: One way to do this is to use a string template engine, like the Apache Velocity Engine, to generate your source code. This can be integrated in you buildung process, if you use Maven for example.

Comment: I am sure there must be a way to do this but the question is do you really need it? Why not use a simple map with key which are dynamic field names and the value the actual object? You can achieve the same result.

Comment: @Whymarrh i just need to name object without specifying the exact name in the code ,since the number of objects i need to create can vary.does not have to be exactly from a file.i just mentioned it as an example

Comment: @user3638700 As others have pointed out, you are likely looking to use some sort of array or list data structure.

Comment: @user3638700 The important question is this: "Once you have them, how do you intend to use them?"

Comment: I think @Vertex got it.

Comment: i am trying to use variabes from each object at different times.and i need to read the values from a file.

Comment: Good first post :) @chrylis would be correct.

Comment: In Java objects don't have names (unless you define a "name" instance variable in the object).  You're talking about the object REFERENCES, not the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a "dictionary" file for your names (that will contain 1:one, 2:two, ...)

Then you'll have to parse that file and create a java file :

```
public String createFileContent( List<String> variableNames ) {
  StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
  for( String name : variableNames ) {
    buffer.append( "Example " ); 
    buffer.append( name ); 
    buffer.append( " = new Example();" ); 
    buffer.append("\n");
  }
  return buffer.toString();
}
```

For more advanced code generation, you might consider using specialized technologies like 
https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/
http://www.stringtemplate.org/
or more generic solutions : 
http://java-source.net/open-source/template-engines